# Can't run packaging.json defined scripts on termux

Tags: android, node.js, termux

I'm setting up a mobile node environment but I can't figure out why I can't run scripts defined in package.json using Termux, I get the following error log when trying `npm run prettier` or any other script

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/data/data/com.termux/        files/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'prettier' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prettier' ]
5 info lifecycle examplepackage@1.0.0~prettier: examplepackage@1.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle examplepackage@1.0.0~prettier: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle examplepackage@1.0.0~prettier: PATH: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/examplepackage/node_modules/.bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/applets
8 verbose lifecycle examplepackage@1.0.0~prettier: CWD: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/examplepackage
9 silly lifecycle examplepackage@1.0.0~prettier: Args: [ '-c', 'prettier --write  main.js' ]
10 info lifecycle examplepackage@1.0.0~prettier: Failed to exec prettier script
11 verbose stack Error: examplepackage@1.0.0 prettier: `prettier --write main.js`
11 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
11 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
11 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
11 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
11 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
11 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
12 verbose pkgid examplepackage@1.0.0
13 verbose cwd /data/data/com.termux/files/home/examplepackage
14 verbose Linux 3.18.31-perf-g64ca40a-00128-g77c6b6b
15 verbose argv "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node" "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/npm" "run" "prettier"
16 verbose node v8.9.3
17 verbose npm  v5.6.0
18 error file sh
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error errno ENOENT
21 error syscall spawn
22 error examplepackage@1.0.0 prettier: `prettier --write main.js`
22 error spawn ENOENT
23 error Failed at the examplepackage@1.0.0 prettier script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

given the following basic package.json

```
{
  "name": "examplepackage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.9.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"prettier": "prettier --write main.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

'npm verify'  and  'npm audit fix' might help you to narrow it down  to specific uuid of the node to id the actual json that is corupt  and in what pkg and possibly uninstall and reinstalling just that pkg